# How to add a value to the final product that would not be multiply by the number of products from the basket?

Tags: module, price, attribute-value

How to add a value to the final product that would not be multiplied by the number of products from the basket?

If I have for example a wedding invitation that I want to sell on my website and the price is 2 euros and I want to include somehow a value of 20 euro that it will be added to the final price. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Which Magento version are you using?